# iOS Swift -> Bluetooth device doesn't show "I" icon under Settings->Bluetooth-> Device

Tags: ios, swift

iOS Swift -> Bluetooth device doesn't show "I" icon under Settings->Bluetooth-> Device.

I have connected to a hardware device. And it is shown under Settings-> Bluetooth as Connected. But there is no way to tap on the device name. Is there any way to show info icon next to the device status and "Forget the device" from iPhone Settings. I am able to forget or disconnect from my app. But I don't know if I am missing anything in Bluetooth connection integration code.

Answer (score 1):

This indicates that it's a BLE connection rather than a Classic (BR/EDR) connection. BLE connections pair differently, and do not include a "Forget this device" option (nor generally do they need one). For some devices you will see both an entry with an (i) and one without. That means there is both a Classic and BLE connection. This is normal for some devices.